# Setting datagridview in editing mode

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I am working on a c# datagridview project where my requirement is that as soon as the datagridview gets focus it's first cell of first row and first column should get focus and that cell should come into edit mode . I mean that i can straightforward type into that cell  . Any suggestions for that . Which event and code i have to use .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the `Enter` event of the `DataGridView`.

I added a simple `DataGridView` to my form and added its `Enter` event. Here's my testing code:

```
public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    // empty row and column so you have something to edit
    dataGridView1.Columns.Add("col1", "Column 1");
    dataGridView1.Rows.Add();
}

private void dataGridView1_Enter(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    dataGridView1.Rows[0].Cells[0].Selected = true;
    dataGridView1.BeginEdit(false);
}
```

If your `DataGridView` already has a data source, you need to be careful about the data type of the first column and the data that will be typed.

Comment: Thanks . One more query can you pls give me code how to set focus to datagridview on form' s load event , just to check this code

Comment: Just set the datagridview `Tab index` property to 0. And don't forget to change the tab indexes of the other controls to values greater than 0.